# Sharing with Cordova App

Tags: cordova

I am looking for some input regarding the following which I could not find information about.

In Devices, when we select a "file" or "image" in file explorer/browser,

device native OS gives us option "share" and displays list of Apps available ex: Facebook, Twitter or WhatsApp etc for sharing.

Now how to achieve that for Cordova App.

Which plugin is useful for this!?

This cordova-plugin-share or Social Share plugin from Eddy Verbruggen plugin is useful for

from my Cordova App to Facebook or twitter or other Social Media.

I am looking for, from Device File Folder to My Cordova App

Comment: You are looking to 'share' from your app, or you are looking to 'open' your device 'Files' inside your app?

Comment: The best way to understand is, 1. Take your device 2. go to file browser 3. select a File or image, device will display "SHARE" option, now you click on it, it will show you "apps" in the device those can be used to "share". This is what I want to achieve, where my Cordova App also get listed in that list among other apps. how to do that and which plugin helps us to get that?